# Does auto-tune make singing (without talent) easy?

Tags: music, musicians

Has autotune made singing as easy as people claim? Or is it just a tool that *slightly* aids already trained singers?

For an example of the claim, see this (SFW) [parody music video, by KSics and Alex](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S46Md0cfiVY).

I've never tried autotune (but I will soon). Is it really the end of any trust in 'the professionals'?

Comment: Those are the tags you should have used :) When you get more rep, you can make new ones but jokey and specific ones like "show-must-go-on" would probably be frowned-upon.

Comment: yeah, the other sites (in the network) are very serious (rightly so), but this one seems especially welcoming to fun :) thnx for the info.

Comment: @b0x0rz I don't know about that! There are some hard-nosed bastards around these parts :P

Comment: "hard-nosed bastards" - citation needed

Comment: Auto-tune usually makes it worse.

Comment: I don't have talent, and find it very easy to sing without autotune.  Finding someone to LISTEN to me sing without it is hard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Has the autotune phenomena really made singing as easy as people claim?

Here's an example of autotune: [Carl Sagan - 'A Glorious Dawn' ft Stephen Hawking (Symphony of Science)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSgiXGELjbc)

It's an example of someone (Carl Sagan) singing without, obviously, even trying to sing.

Comment: #1 i love that guy. #2 jesus christ we've ruined singing with autotune lmao - there is my answer - anyone can sign now lmao. thnx for the quick reply.

Comment: amendment to #2 maybe not ruined, maybe LIBERATED singing with autotune?

Comment: The autotuning is quite noticeable in that song. Now that you know what autotuning sounds like, you'll hear/notice it in other songs (you might also notice, in contrast, some singing where there is no autotuning present).

Comment: yeah. however the song is still great. sagan would love it. another GREAT example of technology (almost completely) removing a complete profession. imagine what a few more years/decades will bring.

Comment: Autotune, like digital sampling is basically just another instrument, it all depends on how it's used within a given work/piece/song. Can be used to create amazing effects, or, crank out top 40 pop songs which can sometimes appear to some to be completely devoid of artistic integrity. It all depends on the capability of the artist using it